# Can I store additional information inside a polygon of boost::geometry?

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, polygon, boost-geometry

I am new to boost::geometry and C++ and while playing around with it, the following question came to my mind:
Is it possible to store additional information directly inside a polygon, like a std::string containing the color or an int with some ID number?
Or do I have to wrap it with something like:

```
MyPolygon {

  typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_2d;
  typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_2d> polygon_2d;

  polygon_2d poly;
  std::string color;
  int id;
  etc...

}
```

Thanks!
ffranz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store any extra information to geometries supported by Boost.Geometry.

But you cannot store this information in the types provided by the library itself.

So you have to wrap them, indeed, or you can create your own types and adapt them to Boost.Geometry using traits.

This example will help you: [Custom Polygon Example](https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/master/example/c06_custom_polygon_example.cpp)

Comment: Thank you, I successfully adapted the example to cover my needs.